# How to center a threejs camera target from a series of loaded json?

Tags: json, three.js

Hello I need  help to find a better way to center the camera target on the centroid of a series of json loaded. I am writing an application which loads json from a database and display the 3D models inside the browser. Some models are made of several parts ( sometimes 10-20 different json ).

I wrote this function which allows to collect all the json into a single mesh. I call this function every time I load a json file:

```js
function unifyComponents( mesh ) {

        mesh.updateMatrix();
        singleGeometry.merge( mesh.geometry, mesh.matrix );
        if( !( singleMesh instanceof THREE.Mesh ) ) {
            singleMesh = new THREE.Mesh( singleGeometry );
        }
        else {
            singleMesh.geometry.merge( mesh.geometry, mesh.matrix );
        }
```

Once I have all the components merged into a single mesh I call this other function to find the center:

```js
function getCenter( mesh ) {

        var center = new THREE.Vector3();
        var centerMin = new THREE.Vector3();
        var centerMax = new THREE.Vector3();
        mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        centerMin = mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min;
        centerMax = mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max;
        center.x =  ( Math.round( ( Math.abs(mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.x + mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.x ) / 2 ) * 100 ) / 100 );
        center.y = ( Math.round( ( Math.abs(mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.y + mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.y ) / 2 ) * 100 ) / 100 );
        center.z =  ( Math.round( ( Math.abs(mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.z + mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.z ) / 2 ) * 100 ) / 100 );
        return center;
    }
```

After that I call scene.remove(mesh);

The problem is that the browser rapidly eats an enormous amount of memory as it starts collecting all the json into a single mesh, around 1GB or more. Since this "duplicated" mesh serves only to find the center not for displaying purpose, it's a complete waste of resources.
So I guess the problem lies in the way I thought the function unifyComponents().

Is there a better way to get around this problem?

Here's what I did following your suggestion about grouping json togheter:
I call this function every time I load a json

```js
function addGroupComponents( mesh ){
groupComponents.add( mesh );
}
```

Then use this one to find the center.

```js
function getCenterOfMesh() {

    var center = new THREE.Vector3();
    var boundBox = new THREE.Box3();
    boundBox.setFromObject( groupComponents );
    boundBox.getCenter( center );
    console.log( "center is: " + " X=" + center.x + ", Y=" + center.y + ", Z=" + center.z );
    return center;
}
```

But I get in return always a vector with values 0,0,0. Obviously there's something I did in the wrong way.

Comment: Have you considered to put all your JSON models into an instance of [THREE.Group](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Group) and then just center the group object via [Box3.setFromObject()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box3.setFromObject)?

Comment: Hello and thx for your reply. But how exactly should I use Box3.setFromObject()? Sorry I am a real noob coder  :)

Comment: You would add all json models to the group and then use it as an argument for `Box3.setFromObject()`.

Comment: If my suggested approach does not work for you, consider to share your code as a git repository or a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/).